# Having Issue on Unwrapping Checkbox Parent

Tags: javascript, jquery

Can you please take a look at [this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Behseini/04q9qyj6/7/) and let me know why I am not able to ONLy  remove the `.check-wrap` classes if exist? what is happening now the `.unwrap()` is even removing the `.well`

```js
$("#un-mask").on("click", function() {
  if ($("input:checkbox").parent().is('.check-wrap'))
    $("input:checkbox").unwrap("<span class='check-wrap'></div>");
});
```

```css
@import 'https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css';
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="well">
    <input type="checkbox" />
    <span class="check-wrap">
    <input type="checkbox" />
</span>
    <span class="check-wrap">
    <input type="checkbox" />
</span>

  </div>
</div>

<button class="btn btn-default" id="un-mask">Yes</button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery's `.unwrap()` method does not accept any arguments. It removes the parent of every matched element. Since your div.well is the parent of the first checkbox input, it is also removed.

One way to fix this would be to wrap the first checkbox input in a tag of some kind just like the others:

```js
$('input:checkbox').unwrap();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="well">
    <span class="check-wrap">
      <input type="checkbox" />
    </span>
    <span class="check-wrap">
      <input type="checkbox" />
    </span>
    <span class="check-wrap">
      <input type="checkbox" />
    </span>
  </div>
</div>

<button class="btn btn-default" id="un-mask">Yes</button>
```

https://api.jquery.com/unwrap/

Comment: Thanks for reply Daniel, is there any other solution to fix this?

Comment: On a different topic, you should also store the return value of `$("input:checkbox")` in the second line in your snippet to avoid a repeat of the same DOM query on the third line.